# How can I specify three conditions for number of lines on a page with figures and tables as well as widow/orphan requirements?

Tags: graphics, widows-orphans

I have to adhere to the three following strict guidelines and I want to do the best I can when I create my Dissertation.

1. There should be at least 6 lines of text on a page with figures or tables.
2. Do not place figures and tables between text.
3. **Avoid leaving a subheading at the bottom of the page**:  Because
   freestanding subheadings must be followed by at least two lines of text,
   the bottom margin may vary slightly on pages with freestanding
   subheadings. At least two lines of text must be placed on the last page of
   any titled section/chapter of the manuscript

I believe the answer to part 3 is to use the package `nowidow` which should address two lines issue after a subheading.

```
\RequirePackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}
```

I'm not sure how to address bullet points 1 and 2.

I don't believe the `float` package will work because of bullet point 2:

```
%--------------------------------%
\begin{figure}[htbp!] % [H]
    \centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {Linear_vs_Rotate_Data_3}
    \caption{Average peel force measurements from the rotational tests were
    within 1.3\% of the average peel forces measured from linear peel tests
    using ASTM standard D6862-11. Only one rotational peel test is plotted for
    clarity.}
    \label{fig:Linear_vs_Rotate_Data_3}
\end{figure}
%--------------------------------%
```

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: figures will never be placed mid page by default unless you allow them with `h` and latex will make sure a minimum amount of text appears on pages that have text and floats but `!` says to ignore those constraints so the `[htbp!]` option directly undoes latex supporting your points 1 and 2. On on widows the semi-autiomatic mechansims of the widows-and-orphans package will give better results than nowidows

Comment: point 3 (two lines after a heading) is the default latex settings that should need no package at all.

Comment: Thank you, let me help clarify your response.  If I change the figure/table option to just ```[tbp]``` this would allow figures to only be a the top/bottom/graphics page and not in between text?  That makes sense regarding the ```!``` modifier.

Comment: yes but tbp is the default so you can simply delete the option

Comment: If the `p` option is actually used the figure will be put on a page with no text as it is too long; this voids requirement 1. Somewhere on this site there are details about float placement parameters but I can't remember/find them. Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goosens *The LaTeX Companion* Addison Wesley, section 6.1 describes these. The `memoir` manual (`> texdoc memoir`) section *10.4 Where LaTeX Puts Floats* also describes these and how to adjust them.